# javascript: find all matched keywords in a string

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js

I am trying to parse a big chunk of text to find all the matched keywords.

I have all the keywords in an array.

for eg:

```
var string = "hi, I need support for apple, android and nokia phones.";

var keywords = ['apple', 'nokia', 'android'];

for(i=0;i<keywords.length; i++){
    var match = string.match(keywords[i]);
    console.log(match);
}
```

This is kind of working for now. Just looking for a better and efficient solution.

Comment: This question would be more suited for our [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) sister site.

Comment: Combine your keywords into a regular expression.

Comment: Adding a \b word boundary is important if you want to match words rather than substrings (ditto for case insensitivity) `string.match(new RegExp("\\b" + keywords[i] + "\\b", "gi"));` assuming nothing within the keywords needs escaping (Better with no 'g' if you don't need to count matches)

Comment: How big is "big"? How many keywords do you have? Do they overlap? Do you only want to search for whole words? Do you need all matches or just test for at least one of them to be apparent?

Comment: @Bergi big is like a mail body and around 25-30 keywords. Keywords dont overlap but string can have multiple occurrences of a keyword. I want to search for whole words. I want to get all the matched keywords.

Comment: @ChiragJain: A mail body is a *small* chunk of text :-) You hardly will need to optimize anything there - or are you searching through many small texts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @freakish said, combining them into one regexp is more efficient (given a decent regex engine). Of course that requires the matches not to overlap, if you need such you must test them one-by-one.

```
var match = string.match(new RegExp(keywords.join("|"), "g"));
```

Comment: this works but would give me duplicate matches if the string contains multiple keywords. should i loop and remove the duplicates?

Comment: So you only want to know for each keyword whether it does occur at least onece? Wasn't clear from your question.

Comment: @ChiragJain: I don't think you can use a single regex then more efficient than what you already have - yet you might want to switch from `match` to `indexOf` or a `new RegExp("\\b"+keyword+"\\b").test`

Comment: going with match is jsperf in chrome shows thats faster. I removed boundary as matching keywords as substrings is also fine. jsperf here: http://jsperf.com/test-indexof-v-s-regex/4

Comment: btw, i am using node.js so m considering chrome test only though indexof is much faster in firefox. Anyways there is marginal difference in all of them. Though you Bergi and @AlexK for all the help and discussion.

Answer (score 1):

One way; case-insensitive, whole words, no dups;

```
var string = "hi, I need support for apple, android and nokia phones.";

var keywords = ['apple', 'nokia', 'android'];
var results = [];
for(var i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++) {
    if ((new RegExp("\\b" + keywords[i] + "\\b", "i").test(string)) {
        results.push(keywords[i]);
    }
}

alert( "contains: " + results );
```

Comment: Yes i thought of this solution. I was wondering if we can get it done with just one regex. What do you think?

Comment: Possibly, but I can't see how to do it in a single expression whilst suppressing duplicates.  Looping each term will still be so fast as to be unnoticable

Comment: Ok. How about one regex with dups. and then we loop on results to remove dups. Will that be fast over multiple regex?

Comment: @ChiragJain: Test it!

Comment: No idea, jeperf.com some tests.  This sounds like a premature optimization tho, i.e. not something that needs to be optimised at all as its so far below human perception its effectively instant even with large inputs

Comment: @AlexK.: It absolutely is. As stated, he searches for 30 keywords in a *mail body* :-)

Comment: missing a "string" somewhere in your code example, right ;) ?